# JavaScript: Custom Function For Path's "d" attribute

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I'm trying to build a function that I can re-use throughout my JavaScript for editing the "d" attribute of SVG paths.

At the moment, I'm able to get the attribute and change it, however it's on an ad-hoc basis. I'd like to create a reusable function.

For example if I have an SVG like this:

```
<svg>
<path class="myPath" d="M25.914,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5" />
</svg>
```

To edit the "d" attribute with JavaScript I do this:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".myPath"); 
element.setAttribute("d", "M475.385...");
```

How could I turn this kind of workflow into a reusable function? The function should do the following:

1. Query an SVG by class name.
2. Query that SVG's path element by class name.
3. Get the "d" attribute of that path.
4. Change the "d" attribute.

I want to be able to set this up so that I can simply call a function that does this and all I need to do is set the "d" attribute at the end. I believe the best way to do this would be through some sort of custom RegEx.

Comment: I don't think it is clear why you want a RegExp and why you want to get the attribute--do you want to modify only a part of the existing path?

Comment: No I want to change the path's "d" attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not understanding you, but doing what I understand you are asking is quite easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/m9K5d/

```
function setPath (svgClass, pathClass, newPath) {
  var element = document.querySelector('.' + svgClass + ' .' + pathClass); 
  element.setAttribute("d", newPath); 
}

// Assuming you add a class "mySvg" to the <svg> element
setPath('mySvg', 'myPath', 'M475.385,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5');
```

Or if you wish to reuse the same classes without needing to supply them each time, you could either do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/YD4R6/

```
function getPathSetter (svgClass, pathClass) {
    return function (newPath) {  
        var element = document.querySelector('.' + svgClass + ' .' + pathClass);
        element.setAttribute("d", newPath);
    };
}

// Assuming you add a class "mySvg" to the <svg> element
var ps = getPathSetter('mySvg', 'myPath');

ps('M375.385,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5');

setTimeout(function () {
    ps('M75.385,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5');
}, 3000);
```

...or, especially if you might wish to expand what you could do with the classes, you could do:

http://jsfiddle.net/KD2DL/1/

```
function Path (svgClass, pathClass) {
    this.svgClass = svgClass;
    this.pathClass = pathClass;
}

Path.prototype.getPathElement = function () {
    return document.querySelector('.' + this.svgClass + ' .' + this.pathClass);
};
Path.prototype.set = function (newPath) {
    var element = this.getPathElement();
    element.setAttribute("d", newPath);
};
Path.prototype.get = function () {
    var element = this.getPathElement();
    return element.getAttribute("d");
};

// Assuming you add a class "mySvg" to the <svg> element
var p = new Path('mySvg', 'myPath');

p.set('M375.385,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5');

setTimeout(function () {
    p.set('M75.385,13.143C25.477,8.58,21.678,5,17,5');
    alert(p.get());
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. Thats super useful! And you understood perfectly. This is exactly what I wanted :)